# Convert an equation system to matrix form in Maxima

Tags: matrix, maxima, equations

I have an equation system on the form:

```
eq1 : q = a*x+b*y;
eq2 : r = c*x+d*y;
```

I would like it to get the coefficient matrix, which in this simple case is:

```
T : matrix([a,b], [c,d]);
```

So that I can express the equation system as:

```
eq3 : Q = T . X;
```

Because I want to use `T` in further matrix operations.
(The original equations are what I get from my problem and I don't want to turn them into matrix form manually, as that's what this kind of program is for. But I just can't figure it out)

Comment: In `MATLAB` you use the `jacobian` function. There has to be something similar in maxima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `coefmatrix` and `augcoefmatrix`.

Comment: Almost, It gave me `matrix([a,b,-q], [c,d,-r])` I didn't want the LHS to appear there

Comment: With suitable use of `lhs` and `rhs` I got my wanted matrix. Thanks.